# Bluetooth isn't working on my Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I have already tried all the popular fixed like uninstalling and reinstalling bluez. I just cannot make my bluetooth work. When I boot into my ubuntu system, I see this error that I have attached below. I have no clue what went wrong since I was using my bluetooth just fine till the aternoon, but when I came back to use it in the evening, it was broken.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yioyg.jpg)

Comment: If it’s a usb device, can you check it on another computer (just to exclude a hardware issue)?